# How to disable noisy debug?

Tags: python, twisted

I have simple example:

```
def __call__(self):
    d = client.getPage('www.google.com', timeout = 1 )
    d.addCallback(self.a)
    d.addCallback(self.b)
    return d
```

How to disable "noisy"  debug for Factory class, using in getPage method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `getPage`, the factory object is not exposed to you, so there is no simple way to disable the logging it does.

You can disable this logging for **all** uses of `getPage` by setting `noisy` on the factory *class*:

```
from twisted.web.client import HTTPClientFactory
HTTPClientFactory.noisy = False
```